# getting gridview cell values when clicking template field command button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with a command button in a template field.
Without selecting the row first, how can I grab the first cell value on the command buttons on-click event?

To test, I tried to set a labels text value but I think that as the row is not select first, it won't work

```
Label3.Text = "test " + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the row number as a CommandArgument in the button.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' OnCommand="Button1_Command" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

And grab the correct value from the row and column in code behind.

```
protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Label3.Text = "test " + GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[1].Text;    
}
```

As discovered later, you need to wrap the binding of the GridView into a !IsPostBack, otherwise you'll get an "Invalid postback or callback argument" error.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = myDataSource;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

> Note that searching GridView cells like this (Rows[0].Cells[1].Text) only
>   works with BoundField columns, not TemplateField and AutoGenerated
>   Columns.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.  I tried your suggestion, got this error...   "Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation."

Comment: Weird... Works here, with both `enableEventValidation=true` and `enableEventValidation=false` in the page directive.

Comment: I need to have enableEventValidation=false or it get the error above, if it's false there is no error but the event does not seem to fire.

Comment: Found the error I think, try wrapping the DataBinding of the grid into `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { }`. When I removed that I got the same error. Took me a while to figure that out.
Second I forgot to mention that using `Cells[1].Text;` only works with boundfield, not templates. See my answer to this question stackoverflow.com/questions/39008313/searching-a-nested-gridview-asp-net.

Comment: Just got round to testing this, and with a few tweaks have exactly what I need, so if you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it.  thanks

Comment: Good to hear it works. I've tweaked my answer a bit so you can accept.