# aspx repeater Do something with the data

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have made a webform, and by using a repeater i would like to display the results with the option of approving/disapproving applicants. I have searched high and low, but I am unable to discover how i can use the data of the item in the item repeater. If someone could point me in the right direction as to how i could do this i would appreciate it alot.

So as example. Someone presses the button approve in one of the repeated items. and i would like to do some db query using the email address which is displayed in that item

codebehind:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(((Button)e.CommandSource).Text.Equals("Approve"))
    {
        //
    }
}
```

and this is the aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="Application">
            <table class="auto-style1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="small">Application received:</td>
                    <td class="big"><asp:Label ID="lbl_App_Date" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("app_date") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td class="small">Status:</td>
                    <td class="small"><asp:Label ID="lbl_App_status" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("app_status") %>'></asp:Label></td>                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="small">Email Address: </td>
                    <td class="big"><asp:Label ID="lbl_App_email" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("app_email") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td class="small">Age: </td>
                    <td class="small"><asp:Label ID="lbl_App_age" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("app_age") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Country: </td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lbl_App_Country" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("app_country") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>Platform: </td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lbl_App_Platform" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("app_platform") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p><b>Motivation to join: </b></p>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_App_Moti" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# Eval("app_moti") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Height="150px" Width="60%" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Panel ID="pan_approval" runat="server">
            <table class="auto-style1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="small"></td>
                    <td class="big"><asp:Button ID="btn_approve" runat="server" Text="Approve" /></td>
                    <td class="small"></td>
                    <td class="small"><asp:Button ID="btn_disapprove" runat="server" Text="Disapprove" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39068191/5836671, but instead of the row number you can also send a value `<asp:Button ID="Button1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("app_moti").ToString() %>' OnCommand="Button1_Command" runat="server" Text="Button" />`

Comment: Oh thats brilliant!  Exactly what i need. just 1 unique identifier :)  Merci~